# ament_package version 0.4 and 0.5.0 Chnages , where the code of package parsing is moved

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ament_package version 0.4 and 0.5.0 Chnages , where the code of package parsing is moved.

I was using the parse package from ament_package now with latest ament the code is not there hence having trouble in running some packages.
Can anyone help to figure this out.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303638/ament_package-version-0.4-and-0.5.0-chnages-,-where-the-code-of-package-parsing-is-moved/) by [sainimayankmohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35838/sainimayankmohan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2018-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[catkin_pkg](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/catkin_pkg) is being used as of https://github.com/ament/ament_package/pull/75.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0